# Django Invalid block tag: 'else', expected 'endblock'

Tags: python, django

OK so I'm still fairly new to django and working with it on a personal project. I am receiving this error for the following code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Website News</h1>
    <% if news_items|length > 0 %>
        {% for post in news_items %}
            <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
            {% autoescape off %}
                {{post.content}}
            {% endautoescape %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <h1>There are no posts currently</h1>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Apparently it doesn't like the {% else %} in my if statemtent. I have already done a decent amount of searching and found some somewhat similar issues but their issues all had to do with either improperly nested blocks or a wrong character. I've checked the docs a bunch and can't find anything wrong with my code besides django complaining.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have

```
<% if news_items|length > 0 %>
```

instead of:

```
{% if news_items|length > 0 %}
```

in your code, which is not a correct template tag.

Comment: @That sticks out like a sore thumb!

Comment: oh wow thanks man, I'm blind I was so focused on the {% else %} being wrong I completely overlooked that.

Comment: Definitely planned to, just had to wait for the time limit to expire you answered me so fast :)

Comment: Somehow, I had regular brackets in there, time to get some sleep:)

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use "if" you have to put that inside `{% %}` block .

.

Comment: In my case I missed I did something like `{% if }` which caused this error